# Return value undefined inside subscribe in angular js after fetching the values from REST API

Tags: angular, subscribe

This is the data returned by the REST API

```
{

    "clo_change": 91.0,
    "vam_change": 72.76,
    "sla_change": 94.0,
    "feedback_change": 87,
    "so_change": 69.0,
    "cost": 87277.75

}
```

In my service.ts file I am making the request to the URL

```
public getNewPlanData(): Observable<any>{
console.log("I am here createNewPlanModel");
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8000/newplandata/')
        .map((response: Response) => {
         console.log("I am here createNewPlanModel2");
         return response.json()
        });
  }
```

I am subscribing to the observable in the component.ts file

```
this.mainService.getNewPlanData().subscribe(result =>{ 
      console.log("inside subscribe")
     this.newData=result;    
     console.log(this.newData)         
     }, error => console.log(error));  
    console.log("outside subscribe")
```

When I debug the code in Chrome, during first time the application is not hit and

> the value is undefined and "outside subscribe" is printed

and during the second time I am getting the values from the REST API and the values are printed inside the subscribe loop but it is not coming to the next statement of  `console.log("outside subscribe")` instead it is throwing error like

> Return value: undefined

and the values are not used for further processing.

I want the to use the this.newData values outside subscribe loop for further processing. Please help me on how to solve it.

Comment: Look into how to use async event based programming. Together with rxjs streams and the `async` pipe in angular. You cannot use something outside the subscribe, unless it's an immediate resolving observale, which it's not

Answer (score 0):

You can use timeout in this situation which might help to some extent.

```
  setTimeout(() => {
      this.mainService.getNewPlanData().subscribe((result) => {
        console.log('inside subscribe');
        this.newData = result;
        console.log(this.newData);
      },
        (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }, 1000 );
    console.log('now I will have data '+this.newData);
```

Comment: where exactly you are going to use this.newData in your application.Can you post that code as well?

Comment: This portion of code is not getting executed `this.finaldata.push([{axis:"CLO",value: this.newData[0]/100 },{axis:"VAM",value: this.newData[1]/100 },{axis:"SLO",value:this.newData[2]/100},{axis:"Feedback",value:this.newData[3]/100},{axis:"SA",value:this.newData[4]/100}]);` and the `Return value undefined` message is flashed and the application is still waiting for results.